# Entry point - webpack.config.js vs vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

In the `webpack.config.js` file we can set entry file as below.

```
    module.exports = (env = {}, argv = {}) => {
        const config = {
            entry: {
                main: './src/js/main.js'                    
            },
        }
    }
```

But in `vue.config.js` file, how to declare the entry file? I have checked in [doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config). but there is property such that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vue CLI 3 integrates the [webpack-chain](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain) library as another way of configuring webpack.

For example, your config file may look like:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  // clear the existing entry point
  config
    .entry('main')
      .clear()

  // add your custom entry point
  config
    .entry('main')
      .add('./src/js/main.js')
}
```

See the section on [config entryPoints](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain#config-entrypoints).

Comment: thank u. Can we change the output file name? I have changed output directory name by using `outputDir`. Want to change output file name. Is there any way to change?

Comment: You would use `config.output.path('dist').filename('[name].bundle.js');` to change the output file name.

Answer (score 1):

For vue-cli 4 it's:

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  // Clear the existing entry point
  config.entry('app').clear()

  // Add the custom entry point
  config.entry('app').add('./src/js/main.js')
}
```